# Different definitions of fboxsep in different parts of the code

Tags: colorbox

Is it possible to define one value of `\fboxsep` to use in an `\fbox`, for example, and then use another value to use in, say, a `\colorbox`?

Can you define such values locally?

Answer (score 2):

You can make the parameters independent by defining a new length and patching the relevant macro; this will also affect `\fcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\newlength{\colorboxsep}
\setlength{\colorboxsep}{10pt} % exaggerated

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd*{\color@b@x}{\fboxsep}{\colorboxsep}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\fbox{abc} \colorbox{red}{abc} \fcolorbox{black}{red}{abc}

\end{document}
```

You can also use `etoolbox` and `\patchcmd`, but in this case you need

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\color@b@x}{\fboxsep}{\colorboxsep}{}{}
\patchcmd{\color@b@x}{\fboxsep}{\colorboxsep}{}{}
\patchcmd{\color@b@x}{\fboxsep}{\colorboxsep}{}{}
\patchcmd{\color@b@x}{\fboxsep}{\colorboxsep}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]